# PyV8 disable automatic garbage collection

Tags: javascript, python, garbage-collection, v8, pyv8

I'm having an issue which seems to be related with the way Python & PyV8's garbage collection interact. I've temporarily solved the issue by disabling python's garbage collection, and calling `gc.collect` and `PyV8.JSEngine.collect` together every few seconds when no JavaScript is being run. However, this seems like a pretty hackish fix... in particular, I'm worried `PyV8` might decide to collect at an inopportune time and cause problems, anyway. Is there any way to disable PyV8's automatic garbage collection for good, at least until I have a few days to spend figuring out exactly what is going on and thus to actually fix the issue?

Comment: You're having an issue... but what's the issue?

Comment: the issue is that javascript code will randomly stop executing. it used to segfault, but after i did the above fix it no longer segfaults.. however sometimes the javascript simply doesn't run.

Comment: the issue is irrelevant for the bounty, the bounty will go to he who figures out how to conquer V8's garbage collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to disable garbage collection for good by changing the source code of V8.

In V8's source, edit src/heap.cc, and put a return statement in the beginning of Heap::CollectGarbage.

Other than that, it's not possible (AFAICT): V8 will always invoke garbage collection when it's about to run out of memory. There is no (configurable) way to not have it do that.

Comment: Ah I wondered if that was the case. It seems I'd have to patch it myself to implement what I want... thanks for providing a good starting point for that!

Comment: In order for this to work I had to disable snapshotting, like this:
`make x64.debug -j9 snapshot=off`